# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\***\\BA\\Data.xlsx'

Tags: python, permissions

I want to export my python dataframe to the excel File "Data" using this:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\BA\Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Top100', index = False)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\---\\Desktop\\---\\BA\\Data.xlsx'
```

How can I solve this permission error?

Comment: try saving the excel file in the same folder as your python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file Data.xlsx file is opened, pandas cannot overwrite the file.
You can overcome this error by closing the file and writing the data to Data.xlsx